# Capture Layout resize before API 11

Tags: android, android-layout

I am dynamically creating a board, made of views that are dynamically set in a relative layout. In my onCreate i call the constructor of my Board class that creates everything:

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);
    RelativeLayout boardLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutBoard);
    board = new Board(this, boardLayout);

}
```

In my Board class I set the rules for the layer and I also need to set the size of the views I display, and I calculate them starting from the values of `boardLayout.getWidth()` and `boardLayout.getHeight()`

Now the problem is that all the actual draw on the screen is performed only *after* the end of the onCreate method, so at the moment of the creation, the width and height of the layer are zero.

So I decided to set the size using:

```
    boardLayout.addOnLayoutChangeListener(new RelativeLayout.OnLayoutChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLayoutChange(View v, int left, int top, int right,
                int bottom, int oldLeft, int oldTop, int oldRight, int oldBottom) {
                board.setParentLayoutSize(left, top, right, bottom);
        }
    });
```

Unfortunately this method is available only from API 11 and I must stick to API 10 as a maximum.
How could I perform this? Is there a way to listen to layout changes without using this method?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

The most elegant solution is to extend RelativeLayout class, then you can just override onSizeChanged:

```
protected void onSizeChanged (int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh)
```

If you need to know the size just after inflate you can try to measure view manually: so call measure(...) than layout(...) and then getMeasuredWidth()/getMeasuredHeight should return the correct size. But this is more tricky, don't use it if you're not sure how it works.

Answer (score 1):

After hours that I could not find anything, I wrote this message and immediately discovered this:
[How to retrieve the dimensions of a view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142090/how-do-you-to-retrieve-dimensions-of-a-view-getheight-and-getwidth-always-r/11422556#11422556)